# Not able to change the font size and color of my collectionView cell's button

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am populating my CollectionView cell programmatically with two labels and two buttons. I have looked on stack overflow for a few different ways to change the title font size and color of the buttons, and textcolor of the labels. This is the solution for most of the problems I find, but it still doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

code for my labels:

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "name"
    label.font = label.font.withSize(13)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

code for my buttons:

```
let kickButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Kick", for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 6)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
```

code to create a new cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "playerItem", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCollectionViewCell
    cell.setupViews(parentSize: Int(self.playerCollectionView.frame.width))
    print(self.playerArrayList[indexPath.item].userName)
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you try `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)` and see it changes font?

Comment: And button's font and color should be changed by `btn.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)`, `btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 6)`

Comment: It works! Thank you @Ryan!